# Curl_setopt in C#

Tags: c#, php, curl, httpwebrequest

I have PHP code like below and I want to write a function which makes the same job in C#. However, I didn't understand what curl_setotp does, exactly. How can I write a function like that?

```
public static function sendDataAuth( $url, $doc,$authData) {
        
    $ch = curl_init($url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $doc);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('OpenPayu-Signature:'.$authData));
            
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: it simply changes some settings inside curl, e.g. curl defaults to `GET` requests, so curlopt_post=>true changes it to use a `POST` instead.

Comment: In fact, curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $doc) and curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('OpenPayu-Signature:'.$authData)); make me confused. Can you explain theese?

Comment: http://php.net/curl_setopt   just read the docs. all the options are listed there

Comment: @mavera `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is just a header to send and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is data to send.

Comment: @loler Thanks for your help. Move this comment to your answer. Then I'll check it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl_setopt` sets some options for cURL. You can see what these options mean on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is just a header to send and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is data to send.